# outlook 2013 in-browser inbox is adding style attribute to my table and destroying the alignment

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, center

EDIT: I have added a fiddle to better demonstrate what is happening since the person who has taken the time to offer an answer (thanks!) does not seem to get what I was asking, so hopefully this helps to clarify
http://jsfiddle.net/t5sPL/

I am sending an HTML email. It renders fine in gmail, outlook desktop client, and several other email clients. however, when viewing an inbox online in the outlook webmail app, http://portal.microsoftonline.com, Microsoft seems to be doing its best to not let me center the contents of a table. Tipped off by this article

https://litmus.com/blog/hotmail-and-outlook-com-drop-support-for-margin

I see that the `margin` attribute is no longer supported. I tried using `padding` instead and no luck. So, to center my table, I thought I could go oldschool and use this pattern to center it:

```
<table width='100%' style='width:100%'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                <table width='700' style='width:700px'>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Content to be centered</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

however, this still does not work, because in my `<td align='center'>` tag, outlook is inexplicably attaching a `style='text-align:center;'` attribute, for a result of

```
<td align='center' style='text-align:center;'>
```

which effectively justifies the content to the left. When I use "inspect element" and delete the style attribute, everything looks as expected.

**Has anyone dealt with this issue before? Any resolution, or explanation?** Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to center the content inside the 700 wide table? If so, add `align="center"` to the table cell it is in:

```
            <table width='700' style='width:700px'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">Content to be centered</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

If you are trying to left align the 700 table content, but have the 700 table itself centered, just add `align="left"` to the `<td>` instead.

UPDATE:

Based on your jsFiddle - This should fix it:

```
<table width='100%' style='width:100%' border=1>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align='center' style='text-align:center'>
            <table align='center' width='700' style='width:700px' border=1>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left'><b style='color:red'>This content used to be aligned incorrectly...</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: No, I want the outer table to be the width of the whole page, which is a container for the 700 table, and the 700 table should be centered inside the container. the content of the 700 table should have left or justified alignment

Comment: Just add `align="left"` instead.

Comment: The alignment of the text itself is not what I'm worried about, what im trying to do is center the table itself on the page

Comment: I've added a fiddle to demonstrate what I am asking, please check it out http://jsfiddle.net/t5sPL/

Comment: @chiliNUT Updated answer. Added align values to your inner table and table cell.